# Intellisense not working for WinRT project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, intellisense

I'm using VS 2012 and developing in C#. 
I've created a solution with two projects: a WinRT project and a Console Application. For the Console Application I get the intellisense working perfectly. Though for the WinRT project the intellisense does not work.

In the Console Application project if I write "String." the options are showed up, while in the WinRT project they don't.

Any tips or information?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/08/fix-visual-studio-intellisense.html)